# Login form [RedirectFromLoginPage] not working, Master Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I am working over a login page in asp.net c# however once I wrote my code it simply does nothing at all. I am using a RedirectFromLoginPage but it seems something is wrong with the code and/or the .net version which I am not 100% sure.

This is my code:

```
 protected void LoginForm_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            using (var context = new CompanyEntities())
            {
                //var collection = (from p in context.CP_BlockedAccounts where p.Email == LoginForm.UserName select p);
                ValidateIfCustomerIsBlocked Validator = new ValidateIfCustomerIsBlocked();
                if (Validator.Validate(LoginForm.UserName) == true)
                {
                    // Account Blocked
                    // Blocked_Alert.Visible = true;
                    // Blocked_Alert_Label.Text = "¡Lo sentimos!, al parecer su cuenta se encuentra bloqueada temporalmente, por favor comuniquese con nosotros lo antes posible para resolver su problema.";
                }
                else
                {
                    var query = (from p in context.CP_Register where p.Email == LoginForm.UserName && p.Password == LoginForm.Password select p);
                    foreach (var item in query)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(item.Email, false);
                        API.CompanyId.CompanyIdentity = item.Id;// Id of the company, global variable
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoginForm.FailureText = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Once this page loads, it redirects to the dashboard page, which is linked with a master page, this is my code on master page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
        else
        {
            if (CompanyId == 0)
            {
                Session.RemoveAll();
                Session.Abandon();
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("~/Login");
            }
            else
            {
                //this.Bind_Header();
                //string ImageURL = "~/API/Handlers/Image.ashx?User=" + CompanyId.ToString();
                //DropDownImage.ImageUrl = ImageURL;
                //MainImage.ImageUrl = ImageURL;
                //ImageSideBar.ImageUrl = ImageURL;
            }
        }
    }
```

The information which I am using is correct such as the password and the email/username however once it gets to the master page it says the user is not authenticated.

Could somebody help me out please with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way I just solved the problem is by commenting the following lines of code in the web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Thanks to all to helped me out. 
**This normally happens when a new project is created.**